# Add rows in data frame if observations are missing

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a df1 with **multiple questionnaires** (measure) per **persons** (id) which were answered at **particular points in time** (date). Normally every person should fill out **three questionnaires per session** (*first, pre, post*). Some participants fail to fill out all three questionnaires. They might only answer one or two of the three. Hence, the possible patterns could be complete (participant A), missing “post” (Participant B), missing “first” (participant C), missing “pre” (participant D), or only having answered one of the three (participant E, F, G).

See df1:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L,  4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), measure = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("first", "post", "pre"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(17558, 17558, 17558,  17558, 17559, 17559, 17559, 17559, 17558, 17558, 17558, 17558 ), class = "Date"), result = c(1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Now, I would like to add missing rows in the dataset with id and measure as well as “NA” for missing date and result. The final df should look like df2.

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), measure = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("first", "post", "pre"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(17558, 17558, 17558, 17558, 17559, NA, NA, 17559, 17559, 17559, NA, 17558, 17558, NA, NA, NA, 17558, NA, NA, NA, 17558), class = "Date"), result = c(1, 5, 4, 7, 8, NA, NA, 7, 2, 1, NA, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

I tried to group_by the combinations which could be missing and insert a row. But this did not lead to the desired result.

```
require (tidyverse)
final <- df1 %>%
group_by(id, measure == "first" & lag(measure, 1, default=NA) == "post") %>%
do(add_row(., measure = "pre", .after = 0)) %>%
ungroup()
```

I also tried

```
final <- df1 %>% complete(id, nesting(measure, date))
```

What, perhaps, makes it even more complicated is that participants could take part in more than one session. Hence, there is the possibility that each id has x * (first, post, pre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should simply be accomplished by `complete(df1, id, measure)`. Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)

df1 <- structure(list(
  id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L,  4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), 
                 .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), 
                 class = "factor"), 
  measure = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), 
                      .Label = c("first", "post", "pre"), 
                      class = "factor"), 
  date = structure(c(17558, 17558, 17558,  17558, 17559, 17559, 17559, 17559, 17558, 17558, 17558, 17558 ), class = "Date"), 
  result = c(1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), measure = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("first", "post", "pre"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(17558, 17558, 17558, 17558, 17559, NA, NA, 17559, 17559, 17559, NA, 17558, 17558, NA, NA, NA, 17558, NA, NA, NA, 17558), class = "Date"), result = c(1, 5, 4, 7, 8, NA, NA, 7, 2, 1, NA, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))

# Result with complete(df1, id, measure) and setting order of measure
complete(df1, id, measure) %>% 
  mutate(measure = factor(measure, levels = c("first", "pre", "post"))) %>% 
  arrange(id, measure, date) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
#>    id measure       date result
#> 1   A   first 2018-01-27      1
#> 2   A     pre 2018-01-27      5
#> 3   A    post 2018-01-27      4
#> 4   B   first 2018-01-27      7
#> 5   B     pre 2018-01-28      8
#> 6   B    post       <NA>     NA
#> 7   C   first       <NA>     NA
#> 8   C     pre 2018-01-28      7
#> 9   C    post 2018-01-28      2
#> 10  D   first 2018-01-28      1
#> 11  D     pre       <NA>     NA
#> 12  D    post 2018-01-27      3
#> 13  E   first 2018-01-27      5
#> 14  E     pre       <NA>     NA
#> 15  E    post       <NA>     NA
#> 16  F   first       <NA>     NA
#> 17  F     pre 2018-01-27      7
#> 18  F    post       <NA>     NA
#> 19  G   first       <NA>     NA
#> 20  G     pre       <NA>     NA
#> 21  G    post 2018-01-27      7

# Desired output
df2 %>% 
  mutate(measure = factor(measure, levels = c("first", "pre", "post"))) %>% 
  arrange(id, measure, date)
#>    id measure       date result
#> 1   A   first 2018-01-27      1
#> 2   A     pre 2018-01-27      5
#> 3   A    post 2018-01-27      4
#> 4   B   first 2018-01-27      7
#> 5   B     pre 2018-01-28      8
#> 6   B    post       <NA>     NA
#> 7   C   first       <NA>     NA
#> 8   C     pre 2018-01-28      7
#> 9   C    post 2018-01-28      2
#> 10  D   first 2018-01-28      1
#> 11  D     pre       <NA>     NA
#> 12  D    post 2018-01-27      3
#> 13  E   first 2018-01-27      5
#> 14  E     pre       <NA>     NA
#> 15  E    post       <NA>     NA
#> 16  F   first       <NA>     NA
#> 17  F     pre 2018-01-27      7
#> 18  F    post       <NA>     NA
#> 19  G   first       <NA>     NA
#> 20  G     pre       <NA>     NA
#> 21  G    post 2018-01-27      7
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Looks like a great solution. thx. Have to check with ‚real’ data. Nevertheless, order of measure in desired output is not first ➜ pre ➜ post. But this could be accomplished either if the date variable is more precise? Or I recode first, pre, post into 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Yep. Recode measure according to the desired order, e.g `factor(measure, levels = c("first", "pre", "post")). I just rearranged to compare the solutions. (;

Comment: df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(measure = factor(measure, levels = c("first", "pre", "post"))) changes factor levels. But arrange(id, date, measure) does not lead to the correct sequence, because "time" is missing after complete.

Comment: Hi Slyrs. Simply change the order of the vars in arrange, i.e. arrange(id, measure, date). Just made an edit to my post to include the code to reorder the factor as well as the order of vars used in arrange.